# Significado alternativo de "espacio": ¿puede ser sinónimo de "habitación"?

Tags: significado, sustantivos, sinónimos, hispanoamérica

¿Se puede usar la palabra "[espacio](https://dle.rae.es/espacio)" como un sinónimo de "habitación"?

Estoy traduciendo un poema del autor colombiano José Asunción Silva y este significado conviene el contexto idealmente, pero el DRAE no da tal variante.

Aquí están los fragmentos del poema con la palabra:

> "Cruzando del **espacio** la negra sombra
>   Filtran por la ventana rayos de luna"
>
> "Y cuando en los **espacios** la noche cierra,
>   El fuego de tu estancia los muebles dora"

Comment: Espacio puede usarse como habitación pero en el contexto no creo que se refiera a cruzar la habitación sino realmente a cruzar el espacio (space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el poema citado, la palabra *espacio* (y su plural poético *espacios*) se refiere realmente al espacio exterior (en la primera cita) y al aire libre o espacio en general (en la segunda). La forma enrevesada de la primera cita, sobre todo, complica la interpretación. Es un hipérbaton:

> "Cruzando del espacio la negra sombra / Filtran por la ventana rayos
>   de luna"

equivale a

> "Rayos de luna, (que vienen) cruzando la negra sombra del espacio,
>   filtran por la ventana."

La referencia a los rayos de luna deja en claro que se está hablando de la oscuridad del espacio exterior.

En la segunda cita yo interpreto “los espacios” donde “la noche cierra” como todo lo que hay fuera de la habitación (“tu estancia”), es decir, el aire libre, el exterior. “La noche cierra” es una expresión extraña. Decimos “noche cerrada” por “alta noche, noche totalmente oscura”. Para el verbo yo usaría una forma pronominal, “la noche se cierra”, pero esto es un poema, así que se permiten algunas licencias.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!